# Como mudar de logo conforme muda de página

Tags: javascript, css

**Resumo:** Pessoal estou querendo fazer uma modificação no site da empresa onde trabalho e não sei como fazer isso.

**PROBLEMA:** Gostaria de criar uma forma em javascript que conforme vai mudando de página fosse alterando a logo que esta localizada no topo/centro do site utilizando Javascript ou até mesmo CSS caso isso for possível.

**Tecnologias Utilizada neste projeto:** ASP.NET CORE MVC, HTML, CSS, Javascript.

**Código da parte que está a logo:**

```
  <div id="header">
    <a href="/" title="Sport Club Corinthians Paulista" class="header-logo" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Links', 'click', 'Home');" style="
        height: 148px;width: 122px;position: absolute;top: 50%;-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);transform: translateY(-50%);left: 50%;-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);height: 50px;z-index: 2;">
        <span class="ct-logo">
            <img class="logo" src="https://dnxstorage.blob.core.windows.net/dnx/publico/FundoTransparente.png" title="DNX Soluções Tecnológicas" alt="DNX Soluções Tecnológicas">
        </span>
    </a>
    <div>
```

...

Comment: Não seria só o caso de mudar o src do img?

Comment: Então meu amigo é que como está em ASP essa parte fica no layout o que replica em todas páginas.
Gostaria de algo com mais dinamismo que quando o usuário clicasse no quem somos por exemplo a logo que está localizada na view shared layout fosse atualizada para a página de destino trocasse a logo.

Se em cada página tivesse uma parte especifica para a logo daria para fazer isso que você me falou, mais como é um código view pai para várias view filhas então não consigo fazer desta forma.

Comment: Então, não seria o caso de colocar um id na logo e executar o comando `document.getElementById(idDaLogo).src = novoSrc;` no js quando a página carregar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode pegar o `window.location.href` e fazer uma verificação com `if/else` e mudar o `.src` da imagem. `if` o `window.location.href` for `== index.asp` vc coloca um `src` na imagem, `else if` outra página (outro `href` na janela) vc muda o `src` da imagem. Vc ainda pode usar `path !=`, caso queira que apenas para as urls diferentes de index.asp tenha outro `src` para a imagem `.logo`

Para entender melhor veja o script abaixo:

```js
let path = window.location.href;
let img = document.querySelector('.logo');

if( path == 'index.asp'){
    img.src = 'https://unsplash.it/100/200';
} else if(path == 'contato.asp'){
    img.src = 'https://unsplash.it/200/200';
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" title="DNX Soluções Tecnológicas" alt="DNX Soluções Tecnológicas">
```